# How do I fix Error a StringVar Youtube Downloader?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a GUI application of youtube downloader using tkinter.but run code Error :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\Amir Mahmoudi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\tkinter\_*init*\_.py", line 1962, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\Amir Mahmoudi\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\Youtub Downloader.py", line 41, in download
yt = YouTube(link)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\Amir Mahmoudi\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytube_main*\_.py", line 71, in **init**
self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\Amir Mahmoudi\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytube\\extract.py", line 133, in video_id
return regex_search(r"(?:v=|/)(\[0-9A-Za-z\_-\]{11}).", url, group=1)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\Amir Mahmoudi\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytube\\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|/)(\[0-9A-Za-z\_-\]{11}).\*
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from pytube import YouTube
from turtle import width

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Youtube Downloader")
window.minsize(450, 200)

def widgets():
    link_label = tk.Label(window, text="Video Link")
    link_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
    link_label.config(font=("None", 15), foreground="blue")

    link_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=40)
    link_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

    place_label = tk.Label(window, text="Directory")
    place_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
    place_label.config(font=("None", 15), foreground="blue")

    place_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=30, textvariable=download_dir)
    place_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="w")

    place_button = tk.Button(window, text="open", width=8, background="blue", foreground="white", command=brows)
    place_button.grid(row=1, column=2)

    download_button = tk.Button(window, text="Download Now", pady=10, command=download)
    download_button.grid(row=2, column=1)
    download_button.config(height=3, width=20, background="green", foreground="white")

def brows():
    directory = askdirectory(initialdir="YOUR DIRECTORY PATH", title="save")
    download_dir.set(directory)

def download():
    link = video_link.get()
    print(link)
    save_dir = download_dir.get()
    yt = YouTube(link)
    yt.streams.first().download(save_dir)
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", message="Your Video Successfully Downloaded")

download_dir = tk.StringVar()
video_link = tk.StringVar()
widgets()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You passed `video_link.get()` to `YouTube()`, but you never did anything to cause that StringVar to have a value, so you're trying to open a blank URL.  Presumably you want to attach `link_entry` to that Var, just like you attached `place_entry` to your other StringVar.